# How to Change This Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this fragment1 and I want to put the java from another fragment in here. Problem is, the java that I'm importing, came from the MainActivity.java, and if I copy it over, it doesn't seem to work. I already imported the strings and the XML for it, just need to know how to properly get that java into this one:

**Current Fragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {

public ConnectFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

**Java that I want to import:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String sign = "";
public String total= "";
public Double tempDouble, tempDouble2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Buttons for Felony
    Button button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    //Buttons for misdemeanors
    Button button6 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button7 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button8 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    //Buttons for Infraction
    Button button9 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    //clear, +, =
    Button button10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button button11 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button button12 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);




    // button 1 event handler
    button1.setOnClickListener(
            //button 1 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 1 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("100 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 2 event handler
    button2.setOnClickListener(
            //button 2 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 2 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("25 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 3 event handler
    button3.setOnClickListener(
            //button 3 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 3 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("10 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 4 event handler
    button4.setOnClickListener(
            //button 4 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 4 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("5 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 5 event handler
    button5.setOnClickListener(
            //button 5 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 5 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("1 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 6 event handler
    button6.setOnClickListener(
            //button 1 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 6 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("1 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 7 event handler
    button7.setOnClickListener(
            //button 7 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 7 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.5 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 8 event handler
    button8.setOnClickListener(
            //button 8 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 8 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.25 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 9 event handler
    button9.setOnClickListener(
            //button 9 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 9 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.013 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 10 event handler
    button10.setOnClickListener(
            //button 10 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 10 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.setText("");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 12 event handler
    button12.setOnClickListener(
            //button 12 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 12 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "+";
                }
            }
    );

    // button 11 event handler
    button11.setOnClickListener(
            //button 11 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 11 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    if (sign=="+")
                    {
                        output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble+tempDouble2));
                        sign="";
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Okay. What's the issue? I see an empty fragment, and your activity code. You put the code into the oncreate view. The only stipulation is you need to, inflate the correct layout, and to use rootview.findview...

Comment: Take a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is breaking because you need to do rootView.findViewById(R.id.the_item_id) to get references to all the UI components.

See the [Fragment API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);
    Button aButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);

    return rootView;
}
```

This will help you